# Forge Model Derivative OBJ translation not correct

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am facing some issue in traslating a model from SVF to OBJ. The idea is to start from DGN to SVF and then from SFV to OBJ.
The process is working correctly but the final result is not accurate at all.

This is the initial DGN file
[image]

And this is the result after the translation
[image]

I am just using the same approach explained in the example for the Model Derivative and basically extending to set the unit and to export the full model

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "{{t5_ossEncodedSourceFileURN}}"
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "obj",
                "advanced": {
                    "modelGuid":"{{metadata_guid_0}}",
                    "unit" : "meter",
                    "objectIds" : [-1]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Is there a different way I can do it?

Comment: is the second image the SVF or OBJ? if OBJ, how are you viewing it?

Comment: They are both OBJ inside Rhino. The second image is the OBJ after been ectracted with Forge from an SVF. The first image is a reference file exported from Microstation

Comment: Can this problem be related with the model being located very far from the origin? The original DGN file is in real coordinates (meters).

Comment: It's possible, models far from origin can appear wrong in the Viewer

Comment: It does not appear wrong in the viewer. Is the geometry that is completely wrong.
The model you see is opened in Rhinoceros, before (DGN) and after the conversion (DGN-->SVF-->OBJ)